# how to use string func startsWith to check on a list of strings instead of one?

Tags: scala

I have a list of names:

```
val listOfNames = List("john", "melanie", "maya", "jack")
```

and I have a string name full name:

```
val fullName = "john legend"
```

and now I want to use the string func `startsWith` and check if the full name starts with any of those names in the `listOfNames`, so how can I check it in one line?

something like

```
if (fullName.startsWith(listOfNames)) {
   //do something
}
```

thanks!!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's a concrete implementation that checks for any matches with the list of names:

```
listOfNames.exists(firstName => fullName.startsWith(firstName))
```

Comment: thank you. in a shorter form: `listOfNames.exists(_.startsWith(firstName))`

Answer (score 5):

Another option:

```
listOfNames.exists(fullName.startsWith)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple: Iterate over your array and repeat the check for each one.